# How to render a CAShapelayer as a retina Image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgcontext, cashapelayer

I've been trying to do this but never succeeded. I have a `CAShapelayer` which has a shape that's defined by a `UIBezierpath`. I want to render it as a **retina image** so when I submask an `UIImageview` with it, I get correct proportions. The Image in my `UIImageview` is indeed a **retina image**.

Here is my `CAShapelayer` code

```
  CAShapeLayer*shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path=forgroungPath.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.bounds = pathRect;
    CGFloat xRect =(CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path).origin.x)* -1;
    CGFloat yRect =(CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path).origin.y)* -1;
    [shapeLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xRect, yRect)];
    shapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pathRect), CGRectGetMidY(pathRect));
    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    [shapeLayer fillColor];
```

I've tried  both

```
 UIGraphicsImageRenderer*renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer 
 alloc]initWithBounds:rectForMainview];
 UIImage*shapeImage=[renderer imageWithActions:
  ^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext*_Nonnull context){
            [shapeLayer renderInContext: context.CGContext];
  }];
```

and

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rectForMainview.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [shapeLayer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage * shapeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

even though I've put 0.0 as scale, shapeImage will not get rendered as a retina image.
Any help is much appreciate.

Comment: have you tried in Retina Devices ?

Comment: @MikeAlter of course i have, I've been trying to do it on retina devices only but  the size of rendered image was always half or one third of what it should be.